# How to Set BadgeElement Background Color?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using BadgeElement(s) in Xamarin iOS in my custom made slideout nav menu.

I just would like to set the background color (like with `StyledStringElements`), does anyone know how?

Comment: So you are using the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the BadgeElement class or use an own created view and an Uiviewelement